# Keras: Using ft_generator and LSTM throws me error: You must compile your model before using it

Tags: keras, lstm, keras-layer

I've followed some posts that suggests feeding an input_shape to the first LSTM layer, yet this error is still yielded:

```
  model.add(TimeDistributed(Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(2, 2), activation='relu', input_shape=(100, 126, 1))))
  model.add(TimeDistributed(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))))
  model.add(TimeDistributed(Dropout(0.25)))
  model.add(TimeDistributed(Flatten()))

  model.add(LSTM(20, input_shape=(100, 62, 1), return_sequences=True))
  model.add(Dense(6, activation='sigmoid'))

  model.compile(loss=categorical_crossentropy, optimizer=sgd, metrics=['accuracy'])

  model.fit_generator(generator=train_gen, validation_data=val_gen)
```

Comment: strange, you are sure compile is executed before fit_generator is called?

Comment: I only have this one line model.compile and it was written before fit_generator, so I am assuming it is executed before fit_gen...